# swiper.js | Stop swiper slide autoplay on mouse enter and start autoplay on mouse leave

Tags: javascript

How to stop swiper slide autoplay on mouse enter and start autoplay on mouse leave? I have tried .stopAutoplay() and .startAutoplay() function but not worked for me.

This is my output : [click here](http://dev.webstarterz.com/slider-test/?preview_id=5&preview_nonce=21c1d61f60&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true)

And here is the js code :

```
<script>
            var slider = new Swiper ('#slider', {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            autoplay: 1000,
            spaceBetween: 0,
            loop: true,
            loopedSlides: 6,
            centeredSlides : true,
          　disableOnInteraction: true,
            autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
            slidesPerView: '1.3',
            breakpoints: {
              600: {
                slidesPerView: 1
              }
            }
            });

            var thumbs = new Swiper('#thumbs', {
                centeredSlides: true,
                spaceBetween: 10,
                loopedSlides: 6,
                loop: true,
                slidesPerView: "auto",
                touchRatio: 0.2,
                slideToClickedSlide: true,
                breakpoints: {
                 600: {
                   slidesPerView: 3
                 }
            }
            });

            slider.params.control = thumbs;
            thumbs.params.control = slider;

              $("#slider").mouseenter(function() {
                slider.autoplay.stop();
              });

              $("#slider").mouseleave(function() {
                slider.autoplay.start();
              });

              $("#thumbs").mouseenter(function() {
               thumbs.autoplay.stop();
             });

              $("#thumbs").mouseleave(function() {
                thumbs.autoplay.start();
              });

    </script>
```

Comment: Instead of mouseenter try mouseover() also try to set autoplayDisableOnInteraction to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$el` element returned from instance. It works fine.

```
slider.$el.on('mouseover', () => {
    slider.autoplay.stop();
});

slider.$el.on('mouseleave', () => {
    slider.autoplay.start();
});
```

Check this example:
https://codepen.io/keitoliveira/pen/XWKdXMr